# The correct way to upload PDF to Google Cloud Automl

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I would like to know whether there is a clear guide to show the steps for uploading the pdf to GCP- AutoML NLP?

1.) I have tried to upload the pdf to the a bucket eg. ABC.pdf

2.) Set up the training.JSONL by replacing the file location with the ABC.pdf

```
{
  "document": {
    "input_config": {
      "gcs_source": {
        "input_uris": [ "gs://automl/ABC.pdf" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3.) I open a new csv, paste the gs link into the file

```
gs://automl/training.jsonl
```

4.) When I create the dataset for AutoML. It shows the following

```
Error: Has critical error in root level csv gs://automl/order.csv line 1: Expected 2 columns, but found 1 columns only.
```

It doesn't show what columns it is required in the guide. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

In the csv file, every line should have the set of the content, e.g.:

```
TRAIN,gs://automl/training.jsonl
```

otherwise it should start with a comma to indicate the first column is empty, e.g.:

```
,gs://automl/training.jsonl
```